# Install git permanently in android studio for mac os?

Tags: android-studio

After update Android studio version to (Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 3), git error occur. Once downloaded and installed, it is ok for a moment. But after closing AS and shutting down laptop and open again, this alert occur and install again. But from terminal git always have been installed in my environment. Why this happen and how to repair this?

[image]

This is my git version and path for android studio.

[image]

Comment: Did you fix it?? I'm having the same problem

Comment: No.... but can ignore it... it is just annoying. Disappeared later why I don't know..

Comment: May be fixed setting as Dev Dabbagh said.

Answer (score 1):

The recent updates from Version Control like Github, bitbucket and GitLab require auth credentials.

for your case try to check the :

> Use credential helper "true"

Comment: In where, please answer more detail.

Comment: @LeoLinux Preferences > Version Control > Git  > check option "Use credential helper" set it checked true.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I solved by downloading the Binary Installer at  Git website and going through the whole installation again. After that, it worked.

PS: Before that, I had the Git installed automatically by XCode